# How to insert dictionary values as arguments in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm outputting an array that will return the amount owed on a loan based on the `loanAmount`, `interest`, and `loanTermYears` for the dictionary `instance1`. The dictionary is printed successfully. However, `calculatedLoanAmount` returns NaN. The function calculateAmount is not properly reading the key-value pairs correctly. How do I properly insert these key-value pairs as arguments so that the function can return the total amount owed?

```js
var info = []
var instance1 = new Object();

var instance1 = {
    Id: 0,
    customerName: "Khawaja Sardar",
    phoneNumber: "745-544-7777",
    address: "New York, NY",
    loanAmount: 5000,
    interest: 6.0,
    loanTermYears: 5,
    loanType: "APR",
    description: "Loan domain for instance1",
    calculatedLoanAmount: calculateAmount(instance1.loanAmount, instance1.interest, instance1.loanTermYears)

    }

function calculateAmount(loanAmount, interest, loanTermYears) {
    var totalMonth = loanTermYears * 12;
    var montlyInterest = interest / 100 / 12;
    var temp = Math.pow(1 + montlyInterest, totalMonth);
    var monthlyPayment = loanAmount * montlyInterest * temp / (temp - 1);
    var sum =+ monthlyPayment * totalMonth
    var totalAmount = sum

    return totalAmount
    
}

info.push(instance1)

console.log(info)
```

Comment: `=+` typo, should be `+=`  Well, maybe it should just be `=` since sum isn't defined before.

Comment: The whole thing is a misunderstanding. Please read how to define a class and use the members inside the class https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: You are looking for something like `const Instance = function(name,.....,.....) { this.id = someIDGenerator(); this.name=name; _self = this; calculatedLoanAmount = function() { return _self.loanAmount * _self.interest * ..... }}; const instance1 = new Instance("Khawaja Sardar",.....,....., );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the way you declare your object. This code simply creates an object of `Instance` with all the data from `instance1`. Try this instead:

```
var info = [];

function calculateAmount(loanAmount, interest, loanTermYears) {
  var totalMonth = loanTermYears * 12;
  var montlyInterest = interest / 100 / 12;
  var temp = Math.pow(1 + montlyInterest, totalMonth);
  var monthlyPayment = (loanAmount * montlyInterest * temp) / (temp - 1);
  var sum = +monthlyPayment * totalMonth;
  var totalAmount = sum;

  return totalAmount;
}

function Instance(instance) {
  this.Id = instance.Id;
  this.customerName = instance.customerName;
  this.phoneNumber = instance.phoneNumber;
  this.address = instance.address;
  this.loanAmount = instance.loanAmount;
  this.interest = instance.interest;
  this.loanTermYears = instance.loanTermYears;
  this.loanType = instance.loanType;
  this.description = instance.description;
  this.calculatedLoanAmount = calculateAmount(
    this.loanAmount,
    this.interest,
    this.loanTermYears
  );
}

var instanceParams = {
  Id: 0,
  customerName: "Khawaja Sardar",
  phoneNumber: "745-544-7777",
  address: "New York, NY",
  loanAmount: 5000,
  interest: 6.0,
  loanTermYears: 5,
  loanType: "APR",
  description: "Loan domain for instance1"
};

const instance1 = new Instance(instanceParams);

info.push(instance1);

console.log(info[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you removed line two, you would get an error saying something like
`'cannot read properties of undefined (reading "loanAmount")'` since `instance1` would not yet be defined. If you want to set an object's keys based on other keys the object contains, you need to do it after the object is created, e.g

```
var instance1 = {
...
}
instance1.calculatedLoanAmount = calculateLoanAmount(instance1.loanAmount, instance1.interest, instance1.loanTermYears)
```